# Quantum Mechanincs - Dirac notation and solving time dependant schrodinger

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, schroedinger-equation, hamiltonian, eigenvalue

The $\hat{S}_{x},\hat{S}_{y},\hat{S}_{z}$ obviously correlate to $x,y,z$ components of the operators.

Consider the Hamiltonian:
                 $$\hat{H}=C*(\vec{B} \cdot \vec{S})$$
where $C$ is a constant and the magnetic field is given by

$$\vec{B} = (0,B,0) $$

and the spin is

$$\vec{S} = (\hat{S}_{x},\hat{S}_{y},\hat{S}_{z}),$$

with

$$\hat{S}_{x} =\frac{\hbar}{2}∣↑⟩⟨↓∣+ \frac{\hbar}{2}∣↓⟩⟨↑∣ $$

$$\hat{S}_{y} =−\frac{i\hbar}{2}∣↑⟩⟨↓∣+ \frac{i\hbar}{2}∣↓⟩⟨↑∣ $$

$$\hat{S}_{z} =\frac{\hbar}{2}∣↑⟩⟨↑∣− \frac{\hbar}{2}∣↓⟩⟨↓∣,$$

where the basis vectors are assumed orthogonal and normalised. Knowing that at $t=0$

$$ ∣ψ(0)⟩= \frac{1}{2}∣ψ_1⟩+ \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}∣ψ_2⟩$$

where the ${∣ψ_i⟩}$ are the eigenvectors of the Hamiltonian, solve the time-dependent Schrodinger equation. Write the solution in terms of the basis vectors $∣↑⟩$ and $∣↓⟩$.

From the question I understand that the Hamiltonian will cancel out the $x$ and $y$ spin operators through the dot product. I have tried following this forward and using a presumed general solution to the time dependent Schrodinger equation but I got no where. Could someone just explain to me how to look at attempting this question?

Comment: In this case you are given an initial state that depends on the eigenvectors. So for your answer you need to find the eigenvectors $\psi_1$ and $\psi_2$ of the given Hamiltonian and add the time evolution to the $\psi_0$. Or in other words add the time evolution of both eigenvectors.

Answer (score 1):

I will get you started with the first bit and finding the eigenvectors to the Hamiltonian, so you are right in that this Hamiltonian is proportional to the $\hat{S}_y$ operator so you need to find the eigenvectors of the $\hat{S}_y$ operator and they will also be eigenvectors of the full Hamiltonian. So we want some states $\vert y_+\rangle$ and $\vert y_-\rangle$ which are eigenvectors, which means they satisfy $$\hat{S}_y\vert y_{\pm}\rangle=\pm\frac{\hbar}{2}\vert y_{\pm}\rangle$$.

Once you have had a bit of experience you will just be able to "see" what the eigenvectors must be for these matrices. Or knowing what an eigendecomposition is helps for this (google it). However, if you are stuck you can always go the old fashioned way by writing out the matrix in the computational basis such that $\hat{S}_y=\frac{\hbar}{2}\begin{pmatrix}0 & -i\\i & 0\end{pmatrix}$ and finding the eigenvectors and eigenvalues by solving the charactersitic equation.

HINT the eigenvectors should be $\pm\frac{\hbar}{2}$. This should really help if you know what an eigendecomposition is (if not I will explain if google isn't helpful).

Also for this bit it is worth noting that the state $\vert \uparrow\rangle=\begin{pmatrix}1\\ 0\end{pmatrix}$ and $\vert \downarrow\rangle=\begin{pmatrix}0\\ 1\end{pmatrix}$.

**I will put the solution at the end of my answer so you don't have to read it if you don't want to.**

It is true that an eigenstate of a system with eigenenergy $E$ evolves in time as $\vert\psi\left(t\right)\rangle=\exp\left(\frac{-iEt}{\hbar}\right)\vert\psi\left(0\right)\rangle$ which is just a special case of general unitary time evolution of a state.

Since the Schrodinger equation is linear we can use the superposition of two solutions as a new solution. I think in the question they want $\vert\psi_1\rangle=\vert y_+\rangle$ and $\vert\psi_2\rangle=\vert y_-\rangle$. From what you have written you can't tell which way round they are but that isn't really important. (I also think my notation is better).

So if you know how each of the eigenstates evolve individually and you know that we can use linear superposition to get a new solution, you should be able to get the form for $\vert\psi\left(t\right)\rangle$. If not comment and I will show some more steps in a few days.

### The Eigenvectors (spoilers ahead)

---

The eigenvectors are $\vert y_{\pm}\rangle=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(\vert\uparrow\rangle\pm i \vert\downarrow\rangle\right)$

Comment: In all honesty I'm totally lost. I think maybe its in my not 100% understanding of the maths. How does the eigenstates evolving and the linear superposition combine to result in an answer?

Comment: @benwhelan94 So if you had two solutions to the stronger equation $\vert 1\rangle$ and $\vert 2\rangle$ another solution would be $\vert 3 \rangle=A\vert 1\rangle + B\vert 2\rangle$ as the Schrodinger eqn is linear ($A$ and $B$ are just normalisation coefficients). Also the time evolution of a state is generally non trivial to calculate depending on the Hamiltonian you have, so a good plan of attack for a problem is to find the eigenstates (we know their time evolution, shown above) and express our state as a superposition of the eigenstates.

Comment: I understand how the superposition works its just in finding the two independent solutions I'm getting lost. How do the eigenvectors above relate to the eigenstates and how does this relate to the final superimposed solution? Apologies if you've already answered this, its a new subject to me and I'm maybe getting stuck in the basics. thank you

Comment: @benwhelan94 I think you may be getting caught up in some of the language used. An eigenstate/eigenvector/eigenfunction are used *almost* interchangeably as terms which refer to the same thing (strictly speaking eigenfunction is used for an infinite dimensional vector space but this isn't really relevant to the discussion). If you think about expressing vectors in real space you normally use the basis vectors $\vec{i},\vec{j},\vec{k}$? But there are an infinite number of basis you could use, i.e. rotating $\vec{i},\vec{j},\vec{k}$ to some new vectors $\vec{i'},\vec{j'},\vec{k'}$ (cont)

Comment: @benwhelan94 It turns out in QM the basis you nearly always want to express your state in is the eigenbasis (the set of eigenvectors/eigenfunctions/eigenstates) for your Hamiltonian. Maybe we should continue this in chat if you have enough rep? (I can't remember how much you need). May I ask are you studying at university/have you taken a course in linear algebra?

Comment: So i have the eigenvectors now and the general solution but how do these combine to result in the final two solutions which can be added to make the overall solution?

Comment: @benwhelan94 Could you tell me exactly what you have worked out so far? It will make it easier for me to explain the rest.

Comment: So i have found the eigenvectors, (via the computational basis), and have them. I just don't understand how they help in finding an actual solution.

Comment: @benwhelan94 do you understand why $\vert \psi (t) \rangle=\exp\left( \frac{-iCBt}{2} \right) \frac{1}{2}\vert y_{+}\rangle + \exp\left( \frac{+iCBt}{2}\right)\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\vert y_{-}\rangle$?

Comment: I can see from the General solution that plus the given solution for t=0 where that comes from yes, why or where that goes i don't know?

Comment: @benwhelan94 What do you mean by "why or where that goes"? It helps me answer you if you are more pointed with the question you ask. I think you need to look up resources on the time independent Schrodinger equation and understand how you get it from the full time dependent version.

Comment: Well i can see that is a solution to the equation, but it seems trivial and that it hasn't used the operator or the spin operations.

Comment: It seems trivial becuase the Hamiltonian is fairly simple, trying to find eigenstates for Hamiltonians in general is pretty non-trivial. This is especially true for systems that have state vectors that live in higher dimensional Hilbert spaces. You then have to diagonalise a much larger matrix to find the eigenvectors.

Comment: Ahhh i think my problem was that i assumed more steps than there actually is. In your notation is the y+ and y- parts representative of the spin up and down bits of the operator?

Comment: Indeed $\vert y_{+}\rangle$ is spin up and $\vert y_{-}$ is down. The method I have laid out here is applicable to any problem and depends on how easy it is to diagonalise the Hamiltonian. The method above from NueroFuzzy is a slick way to solve the problem, you should probably look into some of the useful properties of the Pauli matrices, they are pretty nice :)

Comment: Thank you very much! I'll have a look into them, i'm new to physics stack and i'm very impressed with the community!

Answer (score 1):

I'll tell you a very powerful way to think about this problem. I myself would not find the eigenvectors like Chris2807 did. I'd proceed as such:

The general solution you refer to is $\exp(-\frac{i t}{\hbar}\hat{H})|\varphi_0\rangle$. So, you seem to be aware that this is $\exp(-\frac{i t}{\hbar}C B \hat{S}_y)|\varphi_0\rangle$. It is useful to think of $S_y$ in this way: $\hat{S}_y=\frac{\hbar}{2}\hat{\sigma}_y$, where $\hat{\sigma}_y=-i∣↑⟩⟨↓∣+i∣↓⟩⟨↑∣$  is a [Pauli matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pauli_matrices) with the property that $\hat{\sigma}_y^2=\mathbf{1}$. So we have our solution as $\exp(-i\left( \frac{t C B}{2}\right) \hat{\sigma}_y)|\varphi_0\rangle$. The solution is in your hands: Expand the operator exponential in terms of the series $e^x=1+x+\frac{1}{2}x^2+\frac{1}{6}x^3+\cdots$. Each "$\sigma^2$" in the even terms cancels out to the identity operator and in the infinite sum this gives you a cosine term. Each "$\sigma^n$" for odd $n$ term is just a $\pm i \sigma$ term and you wind up with an i times sine term. You're left with something of the form $(\cos(\cdot)+i\sin(\cdot)\hat{\sigma}_y)|\psi_0\rangle$, which can be solved simply by applying the operators correctly.

The Pauli matrices are very cool and if you learn their properties well you can solve lots of problems like these quickly.

Answer (score 0):

Look again carefully at the way you have written  your spin operator components (up and down together?)and compare them  to any q .m textbook spin components. Maybe it's just a typo in the way you have written the question,

New to this myself but if u and d are orthogonal this would make each spin component equal zero, right?

So I think question is written wrong, you can switch the bra and ket around and get zero

Actually thinking about it, if the question is written correctly, imho they are asking you to consider spin components as operators, i just never saw them written that way before.

It's x and z not x and y that dot product will cause to disappear.

I think I have as much to learn from this problem as you do, good while since I have covered this. Hope some one gives us both complete picture

Ok Ben, that's a great set of answers to read through and my apologies for my mistakes above, but you absolutely do remember and learn from the mistakes much more than anything else. I always get the feeling I should take up knitting insead of physics when the right way of doing the problem is shown to me but that feeling does pass.

I got to learn so much from your question (and my mistakes trying to answer it) that I intend writing it up as a pdf within the next week, so if you are interested in my answers let me know and i can post on my own hosting site, if is this allowed on this forum.

Comment: Thats exactly how it was given to me in the question? Question could be wrong, but its unlikely Thank you for the reply though, any idea on the direction I should take my answer?

Comment: You can not swap the bras and kets round. A bra times a ket is row vector times a column vector which is a scalar. The reverse, a ket times a bra is a matrix.

Comment: Here they have decomposed the operator into a sum of "projectors" (piece of jargon) weighted with each eigenvalue. It can be shown that a given matrix operator $\hat{A}=\sum_n \lambda_n \vert n\rangle\langle n\vert$ where $\lambda_n$ is an eigenvalue and $\vert n\rangle$ is an eigenvector. This is called the spectral decomposition or eigendecomposition of a matrix and is pretty useful for these spin-1/2 problems.